# ProtoBuf - Migration to new version

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I recently migrated to new version of protobuf-net, and i started getting this error message after

Repeated data (a list, collection, etc) has inbuilt behaviour and cannot be used as a subclass

Call Stack Trace

```
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.AddSubType(int fieldNumber = 1, System.Type derivedType = {Name = "InfoColumn`1" FullName = "Om.Common.InfoSet.InfoColumn`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}) Line 83    C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour() Line 431 + 0x32 bytes   C#
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated. I am planning to rollback my code to previous version of protobuf-net

Below is the class info.

```
[DataContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(InfoColumn<Double>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(InfoColumn<String>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(InfoColumn<DateTime>))]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(InfoColumn<Boolean>))]
public abstract class IInfoColumnBase 
{
    [DataMember(Order = 101)]
    public abstract bool IsSingleValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 102)]
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 103)]
    public abstract InfoColumnDataType DataType { get; set; }
    public abstract long Insert();
    public abstract void Insert(long index);
    public abstract void SetValue(long index, object val);
    public abstract void CopyValues(long start, long end, IInfoColumnBase destCol, long index);
    public abstract long GetIndex(object val);
    public abstract void Remove(long index);
    public abstract object GetValue(long index);
    public abstract object GetInternalArrayValue(long index);
    public abstract void Clear();
    public abstract long Count { get; }
    public abstract long ArrayCount { get; }
}

public interface IInfoColumn<T>  : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[double index] { get; set; }
    InfoTable Table { get; set; }
    double Add(T item);
}


[DataContract(Name = "InfoColumn{0}")]
[KnownType(typeof(InfoColumn<double>))]
[KnownType(typeof(InfoColumn<String>))]
[KnownType(typeof(InfoColumn<bool>))]
[KnownType(typeof(InfoColumn<DateTime>))]
public class InfoColumn<T> : IInfoColumnBase, IInfoColumn<T> 
{
    long counter = 0;
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public IList<T> Values { get; set; }

    //[DataMember(Order = 2)]
    bool isSingleVal = false;

    //[DataMember(Order=3)]
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    //[DataMember(Order=4)]
    public override InfoColumnDataType DataType { get; set; }

    public InfoTable Table { get; set; }


    public override long Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Table.Count;
        }
    }

    public override long ArrayCount
    {
        get { return this.Values.Count; } 
    }

    public InfoColumn()
    {
    }

    public InfoColumn(string name,InfoTable table)
    {
        this.Values = new List<T>();
        this.Name = name;
        this.Table = table;
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        this.Values = new List<T>();
    }

    public override void Remove(long index)
    {
        int newindex = (int)index;
        this.Values.RemoveAt(newindex);

    }



    public override void CopyValues(long start, long end, IInfoColumnBase destCol, long startIndex)
    {
        InfoColumn<T> typeCol = destCol as InfoColumn<T>;
        for (long ctr = start; ctr <= end; ctr++)
        {
            typeCol.SetValue(startIndex, this.Values[(int)ctr]);
            startIndex++;
        }
    }

    public override void Insert(long rows)
    {

        if (this.IsSingleValue == true) return;

        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < rows; ctr++)
        {
            this.Values.Add(default(T));
        }
    }

    public  T this[double a]
    {
        get
        {
            if (a >= this.Count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            long index = (long)a;
            if (this.Table.IsFreezed == false)
                index = this.Table.CheckData(a);


            if (this.isSingleVal == true)
                return this.Values[0];
            else 
                return this.Values[(int)index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (a >= this.Count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            long index = (long)a; 

            if (this.Table.IsFreezed == false)
                index = this.Table.CheckData(a);

            if (this.isSingleVal == true)
                this.Values[0] = value;
            else
                this.Values[(int)index] = value;

        }
    }

    public override long GetIndex(object val)
    {
        T item = (T)val;
        return this.Values.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public override void SetValue(long index, object val)
    {
        if (val is InfoSetLink)
            this.Values[(int)index] = (T)val;
        else
            this.Values[(int)index] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
    }

    public override object GetValue(long index)
    {
        return this[index];
    }

    public override object GetInternalArrayValue(long index)
    {
        return this.Values[(int)index];
    }


    //[DataMember(Order=5)]
    public override bool IsSingleValue 
    {
        get { return isSingleVal; }
        set
        {
            if (isSingleVal == true)
            {
                this.Values = new List<T>(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public override long Insert()
    {
        if (this.IsSingleValue == true) return -1;
        this.Values.Add(default(T));
        return this.Values.Count - 1;
    }

    public double Add(T item)
    {
        this.Values.Add(item);
        return this.Values.Count - 1;
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new InfoColumnEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new InfoColumnEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: My psychic debugger isn't working today; can you give me a **hint** of what your type model looks like here? For example, what does `InfoColumn<T>` look like? what base-type and derived-types does it have? what interfaces does it implement? does it have an `Add()` method (this might be significant)?

Comment: i have updated class structure with original question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: re my answer; r480 has been uploaded to both nuget and google-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InfoColumn<T>` has a public `Add(T)` and implements `IEnumerable<T>` (via `IInfoColumn<T>`).

There is wider support for list-like types in v2, and it may be that it is trying to interpret the above as a list. Which indeed, it does look a lot like! I will try to take a look to see if this general scenario can be detected and avoided, but it is an edge case (since it is indeed very list-esque).

There is an existing `IgnoreListBehaviour` switch, however when validating this for the model shown above, it seems that *for this specific scenario* the "you can't do that" fires before the code that disables list handling; I have changed this in the source, and this will be included in the next release. Basically, you can address this by adding:

```
[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]
```

to the impacted type (`InfoColumn<T>`), with the **next** build. Which will be shortly, as soon as I've completed validation etc.

Comment: Thanks Marc for quick turn around. I pulled up latest build and after adding above attribute, it did fixed my code.